# Getting storage usage from Google Contact/People API?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I am trying to get the remaining space of one's Google Contact.

[This FAQ](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/148779) says every account has 20MB / 25000 contacts. But the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest) does not have any REST resource to list one's storage.

How can I get the storage usage/space through People API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

This information is not available to People API nor the deprecated Contacts API.

#### Workaround:

In order to see how many contacts you can still add, you can check how many contacts you currently have via [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) and deduct that from the contact limit (25,000).

#### File a feature request:

If you think this functionality could be useful, I'd suggest you to [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=344199&template=1040408).

Comment: Thanks. How about workarounds of the 20MB storage limit?

Comment: @Dia I'm sorry I totally missed your comment. That's more tricky and it would depend on the language you're using, but I guess it would be related to measuring the size of the HTTP responses.